# How to add a menu generated from a doc type list in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco7

I'm new to umbraco and i want to be able to click in a content field, add content, then select **specialty nav item**.  This navigation would be queried from a custom doc type.

I have the doc type list setup and i have a generic custom grid editor setup, however im not sure how to get the grid editor render portion to actually query the doc type and output it.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but if you want to render custom functionality in a grid, you probably going to need to create a macro for that https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/macros/

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using a macro and a partial template like so:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@{
    var selection = CurrentPage.Site().FirstChild("benefitNav").Children("benefitNavItem").Where("Visible");
}
<div id="benefitmenu">    
    <table class="blink">
    @foreach (var item in selection)
    {
        var img = Umbraco.Media(item.GetPropertyValue("benefitIcon")).Url;
        foreach (var link in @item.linkToPage)
        {

            <tr>
                <td class="bicon"><img alt="@link.caption" src="@img" /></td>
                <td class="btext"><a href="@link.link">@link.caption</a></td>
            </tr>

        }

    }
</table></div>
```